# Insert Multiple Array in Database using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am newbie on Zend Framework. I have these arrays:

```
$pr1 = array('user_id' => '434', 'book_id' => '234');
$pr2 = array('user_id' => '435', 'book_id' => '235');
$pr3 = array('user_id' => '436', 'book_id' => '236');
```

How do I insert these arrays into database using Zend Framework 1? The table name 'book_listing' and have 'user_id' and 'book_id' field.

Comment: Here is the information you need to persist your data in Zend Framework:
https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html

Comment: is there any simple way to insert?

Answer (score 0):

```
$table = new Zend_Db_Table('book_listing');
$table->insert($pr1);
$table->insert($pr2);
$table->insert($pr3);
```

Note that you shouldn't do it like that (unless it's a one-off script), but rather define your own class:

```
class BookListing extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
  protected $_name = 'book_listing';
}
```

Further info can be found in the documentation https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.insert